# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE Manipulate Some Date Columns

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a csv with 3 date columns but each is formatted dd/mm/yyyy H:i:s i.e 27/05/2019 20:25:00

I am trying to manipulate these to insert using LOAD DATA INFILE without any success:

My state looks like this:

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/file.csv' 
    INTO TABLE db_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    SET promotion_starts = str_to_date(@column7, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'), 
    promotion_ends = str_to_date(@column8, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'), 
    date_added = str_to_date(@column17, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%:%i:%s')
```

All other data inserts fine but the date columns are all null

Comment: Where do you set `@column7`, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the line of the query that specifies how the fields of the CSV file correspond to table columns, and defines `@column7` and `@column8`.

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/file.csv' 
    INTO TABLE db_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (foo, bar, baz, xxx, yyy, zzz, @column7, @column8, aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff, ggg, hhh, @column17, iii, jjj)
    SET promotion_starts = str_to_date(@column7, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'), 
    promotion_ends = str_to_date(@column8, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'), 
    date_added = str_to_date(@column17, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%:%i:%s')
```

Replace all the column names I made up with the actual column names in your table that correspond to the CSV fields.